# Is it possible to create libraries associated with projects in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I use Photoshop and Sketch a lot on my everyday tasks. Associating libraries and resources is something I always wanted to have in PS. Sketch does it by default (not everything, but most of it), so maybe wondering if in new versions this is possible in PS and I just didn't find it.

What I mean with this is: **every font, color swatch, style, symbol, etc is saved with the PSD**, so when I open it on any computer, everything is imported with the project without having to rebuild everything. Same if I want to send assets to a client, including fonts, images and so on, just automating the process.

Is this possible? I'd be willing to use scripts or plugins if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing automatic that I am aware of, but if you are using Creative Cloud, you can create a CC Library that includes all of this information, and will be available no matter what document you have open.  These libraries can be shared with others, so that you could share them with a client.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I use CC. This is not exactly what I was thinking of, but it covers my own case (the client's side is trickier because it would require them to have a CC account, right?). Will wait for other answers but I feel like this will be the only possibility (hence teh answer will be correct)

Comment: Yes, anyone that you share a library with must also have CC.